# How do you use a requirements.txt file when deploying from pypi?

Tags: python, deployment, pip

I don't understand python deployments.  You have a requirements.txt file that pins all the requirements for a deploy, that's great.  Now I have my project all zipped up and pushed to a local pypi server.  Now how do I install it from pypi and use the requirements.txt file to setup the exact environment?

I know I can run: 
pip install myproject --no-dependencies
but is there a command to install dependencies from the requirements.txt file instead without first using git to checkout the source? Something like:

pip install myproject -remote-requirements requirements.txt

How is this typically done?

Comment: You can either get the `install_requires` dependencies from `setup.py` or clone the repo to get `requirements.txt`.

Comment: The problem is that install_requires is not a repeatable deployment.  If a third party updates a lib, redeploying will automatically fetch it.

Comment: You can specify versions and ranges in `setup.py`, too. You should read e.g. http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements/

Comment: Seems like I shouldn't have to clone to repo just get the requirements file.   I guess you could argue that the pip distributions aren't supposed to manage deployments, so what is the way to handle deployments so that they are repeatable.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Generally I use `requirements.txt` for *development* reqs, and put *deployment* reqs in `setup.py`. So you generally only need the former in cases where you're already cloning the repository.

Comment: The docs seem to say it's the other way around.  I guess I'm coming from the maven, where after you do a release you'll have a tag in source control with a pom file that you can re use to rebuild the release.  In the end I think we'll end up doing something similar. After deployment, we'll generate a requirements.txt file from pip freeze and check it in somewhere with a version.   Then if we need to rebuild the virtualenv, we'll be able to that.